# Converting Excel to JSON using c# dictionary

Tags: c#, excel, dictionary, json.net

I am using this code to convert an Excel file into a JSON format.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pathToExcel = @"D:\works\sample.xlsx";
            var sheetName = "sa";
            var connectionString = String.Format(@"
            Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
            Data Source={0};
            Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""
        ", pathToExcel);

            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
                    @"SELECT * FROM [{0}$]",
                    sheetName
                    );


                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    var query =
                        (from DbDataRecord row in rdr
                         select row).Select(x =>
                         {


                         Dictionary<string, object> item = new     
Dictionary<string, object>();
                         for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
                         {
                             item.Add(rdr.GetName(i), x[i]);                                

                         }
                         return item;

                         });

                //Generates JSON from the LINQ query
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
                    var result = json;
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    //return json;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The requirement is that I need to create sub serialized object within the JSON. For example, if a cell has a value:
"name": "abc,def", the output must be:

```
"name":
{
 "name1": "abc",
 "name2": "def"
}
```

How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: Please post code as text instead of an image.

Comment: please provide your code in text format here.

Comment: provide code where you are handling "name":
{
 "name1": "abc",
 "name2": "def"
} this part

Comment: @MihirDave can that link be of some help?

Comment: No, post the code here. @CVKASHYAP

Comment: @CVKASHYAP can you give sample Excel data also

Comment: code included in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code this will help you i hope

```
//dynamic item = new ExpandoObject();
Dictionary<string, object> item = new Dictionary<string, object>();
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    if(x[i].ToString().Contains(","))
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> temp = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        string[] data = x[i].ToString().Split(',');
        for(int j=0;j<data.Length;j++)
        {
            temp.Add(rdr.GetName(i)+j, data[j]);
        }
        item.Add(rdr.GetName(i), temp);
    }
    else
    {
     item.Add(rdr.GetName(i), x[i]);
     Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: **Getting the following error:**

Error CS1929 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<string>(IQueryable<string>, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<string>' ConsoleApplication1

Comment: please provide sample xlsx file if you get any other errors so i can help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This code is working but not in the expected format. My expected format is as follows. If the values in **name** are **abc,def**, the output must be **name: { name1:abc,name2:def}** but I am getting the output as **name1:abc,name2:def** according to the code given by you.

Comment: @CVKASHYAP Please check new edit Hope new Edit will give you output as expected.

Comment: Glad it helped please accept answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Hi Mihir. When i am trying to add another level of split, I am getting the following error: 
"Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Any way that I can overcome this?

Comment: please open a new question with code and error message so i can review it properly